# Creating 2D worldbuilding games like Terraria or Starbound in frameworks like PhaserJS or PixiJS?

Tags: phaser, open-world, world-editor

Frameworks like Phaser or Pixi support tilemaps, but I'm curious if that is already enough to get a map where the player can change everything that he wishes. I'm also not sure if browsers would be able to handle this in terms of performance

Comment: Unfortunately, "which technology to use" types of questions are off topic for this site. We prefer actual issues that need to be solved :)

Comment: Terraria/Starbound don't have the whole game world in memory either. They load and unload world chunks while the player moves through the world.